# Are there static libraries without .o files ? Or it's not a static library at this case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries

I've framework `FrameworkStatic.framework` when I opened it I didn't find `.o` files, but `.h` and `.a` only despite that all of comments assure that static library always contains `.o` files.

If my `FrameworkStatic.framework` doesn't contain `.o` files is it static library or not? (If not then it will be possible to open it and find code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static library has `.a` extension. `.o` extension is used for object files. Simplified example of how the static library is created.

Source code:

- `file1.c`
- `file2.c`

Compiled into object files:

- `file1.o`
- `file2.o`

Then static library is created from these `.o` files:

- `libfile.a`

More info in [Static library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) article.

To answer your question - yes, what you have is a static library.

Comment: so  '.a' files are all that I have in static library and no ability to find any code  included

Comment: `.a` file is static library itself - binary. You can disassemble it to check implementation details, etc. And also there is `.h` file (or more), which does contain macros, declarations, ... But it's just declaration like `void a(void);` without body (definition).